# Unable to combine pwd with filenames in Zsh

Tags: zsh, filenames

**Problem:** to combine PATHs with filenames, such that I can easily source many files.

I have two files A and B. `ls` gives their names clearly.

I run

```
pwd `ls`
```

I get the error message

```
too many arguments
```

I did not find an option for pwd which would allow me to have more than one argument.

How can you combine pwd's output to filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $PWD/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sigjuice's answer, if, as you state, you need it for sourcing many files, simply use

```
source ./*
```

It'll probably burn less CPU cycles because the shell doesn't have to create absolute path names for each file.